# How to watch object on unknown scope parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm writing an element directive which can be used inside other directives.
The structure of the parents containing the directive element is unknown.

My directive needs to watch an object called 'modelState' which resides somewhere along the parents scopes tree.
However, I can't tell which parent, which is why `scope.$watch("$parent.modelState", ...);` will now work at all times.

How can I create this watch without knowing who the parent I need is?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your directive code create isolated scope

```
yourAngularModule.directive('yourDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            yourModelState : '='
        },
        link : function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('yourModelState', function (){
                //do something
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your HTML that use directive

```
 <your-directive your-model-state="$parent.modelState"><your-directive>
```

This way your directive only cares about `scope.yourModelState`

Comment: Is there a way without providing the model as a bound attribute?